# Call function in C++ dll from C#

Tags: c#, c++, dllexport, intptr

I'm trying to call a function in a C++ dll, from C# code.

The C++ function :

```
#ifdef NT2000
      __declspec(dllexport)
    #endif

    void MyFunction
            (   long            *Code,
                long            Number,
                unsigned char   *Reference,
                unsigned char   *Result         ) ;
```

And my C# call is :

```
 [DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void MyFunction(ref IntPtr Code,
        int Number,
        string Reference,
        ref IntPtr Result);
```

This function is supposed to return "Code" and "Result"

The "Code" value that I get seems to be ok, but "Result" seems not ok, so I'm wondering if I'm getting the string value that I expect or the memory address ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please show the body of `MyFunction` and please see [mre].  Also, what are you getting and what are you expecting?

Comment: How big is the `Result` buffer supposed to be? There seems no way to pass in a size

Comment: Are you aware that C++ and C# use totally different memory models? For interop between C++ and C# I always use C++/CLI (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes). In any case you will need to ensure C# knows it is dealing with pointers it doesn't own and thus should not cleanup itself.

Comment: My Result is supposed to have a size = 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`long` in C maps to `int` in C#. And `char` is ANSI, so you need to specify `UnmanagedType.LPStr`. The `Result` appears to be an `out` parameter, for which you will need to pre-assign a buffer (size unknown?) and pass it as `StringBuilder`

```cs
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void MyFunction(
        ref int Code,
        int Number,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        string Reference,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr), Out]
        StringBuilder Result);
```

Use it like this

```cs
var buffer = new StringBuilder(1024); // or some other size
MyFunction(ref myCode, myNumber, myReference, buffer);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !
It's almost give me what I expect.
Expected : 39656136788582617901
Result : 396561367885826179011212231543
So I think that as you said, I need to pre-assign a buffer, with a size, how to do that please ?

Comment: It's working with :

StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder("", 19); //The size that I need is 20

Comment: If I use : var buffer = new StringBuilder[1024];
buffer will be an array, so not accepted

Comment: Thank you very much, my problem is solved :-)